# Median of two sorted arrays

Tags: python, array, complexity, median

The task is to find the median of two Arrays. I have an O(n) solution.
Can it be written in a better time complexity?

```
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, A, B):
    combined = []
    while len(A) > 0 and len(B) > 0:
        if (A[0] < B[0]):
            combined.append(A.pop(0))
        else:
            combined.append(B.pop(0))
    combined.extend(A)
    combined.extend(B)

    length = len(combined)
    if length % 2 != 0:
        return combined[length // 2]
    else:
        return (combined[length // 2-1] + combined[length//2]) / 2
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), function and variable names
should be *“lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.”* In your case I'd suggest

```
def median_of_sorted_arrays(a, b):
```

Your code determines the median correctly. However, it modifies the
passed arguments, which might be unexpected to the caller:

```
a = [-5, 3, 6, 12, 15]
b = [-12, -10, -6, -3, 4, 10]

print(findMedianSortedArrays(a, b))   # prints 3
print(findMedianSortedArrays(a, b))   # prints 13.5
```

This could be fixed by accessing the lists via subscripting:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if (a[i] < b[j]):
        combined.append(a[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        combined.append(b[j])
        j += 1
combined.extend(a[i:])
combined.extend(b[j:])
```

The next possible improvement is to get rid of the additional storage:
Instead of storing elements from `a` or `b` into the `combined` list
you could just *count* how many elements have been merged so far,
until the median element is found.

A more efficient algorithm is described in

- [Median of two sorted arrays with different sizes in O(log(min(n, m)))](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-two-sorted-arrays-different-sizes-ologminn-m/)

The basic idea is to partition both `a` and `b` into

```
a[:i] + a[i:]
b[:j] + b[j:]
```

such that the following conditions are satisfied:

```
i + j = (len(a) + len(b) + 1) // 2
a[i-1] <= b[j]
b[j-1] <= a[i]
```

and this can be done efficiently with a binary search. Then the “union”
of the first (resp. second) halves is the first (resp. second) half of the `combined` array, so that the median is

```
max(a[i - 1], b[j - 1])   # if the total length is odd
(max(a[i - 1], b[j - 1]) + min(a[i], b[j])) / 2 # if the total length is even
```